# Chromecast iOS sender app, how to play video in loop?

Tags: chromecast

I have downloaded CastVideos-iOS  (Chromecast sender app available under Google Cast GitHub). Thanks a lot that this app work well.
Few questions:

1. How to play videos in "loop" in  CastVideos-iOS
2. Under media.h 
   It uses MIME as  _mimeType =@"video/mp4";

questions: can media.h can handle any other MIME Type  say "text/html" to Chromecast a html page?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your video to loop, the easiest would be to add `loop` to your video html tag on your receiver. If you want that to be controlled from your sender, you need to do a bit more; the "loop" feature is not exposed through the Cast media apis and you need to catch the end of video playback (status == IDLE, reason == FINISHED) and the play that from position 0 again. Be aware that there is a bug in chrome hat doesn't play media "continuously" if you use the `loop` attribute; there is s light delay (2 seconds or so) and if there is an absolute need to get around that, you need to do a fair amount of work; that might be more required for music though (one work around is to use fragmented audio along with the MSE extension to play fragments one after the other to make sure you get a continuous stream, but it is not a one liner code change, and your source needs to be fragmented, etc)

For other mime types, you can put whatever is appropriate there but remember, if you are using the media channel, you need to provide a media MIME type, and if you have a different thing, most likely you need to write your own receiver and use your own namespace to communicate your messages to your receiver and your receiver should have the capability to handle the item you are throwing at it. For example, passing a url to an HTML page to a Styled Receiver is not going to produce what you would like.

Comment: ThankYou Ali, you said "For example, passing a url to an HTML page to a Styled Receiver is not going to produce what you would like."  You mean "Custom Receiver" is the better options?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to write your own receiver, or [modify ours](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Simple-Receiver), and add the loop element to the tag.

```
<video id='vid' loop autoplay />
```

Comment: Great , thank you. How do we deploy the Receiver in Chromecast device?

Comment: I think it is about the right time for you to read on the development process for Chromecast at https://developers.google.com/cast/, a lot of your questions will be answered there.

Answer (score 0):

[VidCast](http://dabble.me/cast) now allows this using Chrome + extension. Tee up a video and you'll see "Looper" in the bottom right.

Answer (score -1):

```
Under localplayerviewcontrol.h

 else {
            NSURL *url = self.mediaToPlay.URL;
            NSLog(@"Playing movie %@", url);
            self.moviePlayer.contentURL = url;
            self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
          //  self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
             self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
            **self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;**
            self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
            self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
```

When we change self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone; to self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne; it loops in the preview, when you cast to Crimecast then its not looping. Any explanation would greatly appreciated.